# Changing class of all class="like" inside a <div> with particular data-id

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck with changing the class of all the `class=like` spans that are within `<div class="h2" data-id="9">` (one for this example only. There are more on the page).

I need this `$('.h2[data-id="9"]')` just this way, since I need to pick out particular `div`s.

This being the case, how can I change the `class` of all `class=like` to something else. I seem to be going no where with this. You'll see what I'm trying to achieve if you look at my code below.

Can you pls help?

```
success: function(data){
         // Remove class like, add class no-link
         $('.like[data-id="'+data+'"]').removeClass('like').addClass('no-like');

    //For this example
    $('.h2[data-id="9"]').siblings().removeClass('like').addClass('grey');
    },
```

My `<div>`

```
<div class="h1" data-id="8">Restaurants</div>
        <div class="h2" data-id="9">Which is your favourtie restaurant in town?
            <div>* McDonalds &nbsp              <span class="like" data-id="10" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
            <div>* KFC &nbsp                    <span class="like" data-id="11" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
            <div>* The Heart Attack Grill &nbsp <span class="like" data-id="12" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
            <div>* In-n-Out &nbsp               <span class="like" data-id="13" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
            <div>* Popeye's &nbsp               <span class="like" data-id="14" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem of the current code? What does `data` contain?

Comment: $('.h2[data-id=9]')  .. lose the quotations in the selecter

Comment: This question is really similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442291/jquery-cant-change-class-of-all-spans-inside-a-div

Comment: Data is ok. It's the thing below that's the problem.

Comment: Does replacing `siblings()` with `find('span.like')` method solve the problem?

Comment: @undefined No. It does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
function classReplace(data,replacementClass) {
        //$('.h2[data-id="' + data + '"]').children('div').children('span[data-sec="' + data + '"]').removeClass('like').addClass(replacementClass);
  $('.h2[data-id="'+ data +'"]').children('div').children('span.like').removeClass('like').addClass(replacementClass);
};

classReplace(9,'hide');
```

Just pass in the data-id that you want to replace.

Comment: I need to change the `class` for all the `span class="like"` that are inside that `<div>`. How can I specify that? So:  $('.h2[data-id=9]').children('span with class="link"').removeClass('like').addClass('grey');

Comment: Code has been updated to account for divs inside of a div, as well as added a parameter for you to pass in the name of the new class that you want.

http://www2.codepen.io/chase_hubbard/pen/KDEsG

Comment: There's no children('span[data-sec="' + data + '"]'). It's children('All spans with class="like"'). This is the way I hoped to do it - (this is from your answer with a few changes and it works) - $('.h2[data-id=9]').children('div').children('span.like').removeClass('like').addClass('hide'); But I wonder if its correct.

Comment: In your code above, you do indeed have the data-sec on your spans, but if you just want all of the span's with a class of like, then your changes are correct, however do not have the replacementClass argument. The codepen has been updated to accommodate for your request, and still has the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`siblings` method selects the sibling elements of the selected element and target elements are descendants of the selected `div` element, you should use `.find()` method instead:

```
$('.h2[data-id="'+ data +'"]').find('span.like')
                              .removeClass('like')
                              .addClass('grey');
```